# NetworkStream reads fewer bytes than expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, stream, networkstream

If the messageBytes.Length is sufficiently large(say around 30,000), then the stream.Read reads a fewer bytes than expected.

```
Using stream As New Net.Sockets.NetworkStream(socket)
    networkStream.Read(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length)
End Using
```

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx) at MSDN declares this in its **Remarks** section

> An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even
>   if the end of the stream has not been reached.

I was able to read it in a while loop reading single byte until the desired position is reached, like

```
Dim position = 0
While position < messageBytes.Length
    stream.Read(messageBytes, position, 1)
    position += 1
End While
```

The question is can anyone tell why the implementation allows this? I thought the `Stream.Read` method is blocking, so it should wait until all the bytes are available in the stream and are read successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It blocks until *some* data can be read. This is very important if you're processing the data as it arrives. For instance if you're going to write the data to a file, you might as well start writing immediately instead of waiting until all data has been downloaded.

It also enables processing more data than what fits in memory.

You don't need to read it byte per byte though, ie:

```
public byte[] ReadFixedLength(this Stream stream, int length)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    int offset = 0;
    while (length > 0)
    {
        int read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, length);
        if (read == 0)
        {
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        }

        offset += read;
        length -= read;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that the question is in VB.NET, and that the method you provided can be much more clean, let me edit it.